# Add Days word to datediff formula for results

Tags: mysql

Hello i am using the following code to get the datediff on days from 2 dates:

`datediff(Now(),recordadded)`

the results show as just a number, for example: 17
but i need to show as: 17 Days

is there any way to add the word Days to this formula?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
concat(datediff(now(), recordadded), ' Days')
```

though that will produce "1 Days"; if you want e.g. "2 Days" but "1 Day", you would need:

```
concat(datediff(now(), recordadded), ' Day', case datediff(now(), recordadded) when 1 then '' else 's' end)
```

Comment: Great excellent solutions, thanks, i cant vote but you answer got a +